# Looping within a group in sas

Tags: loops, sas

I am trying to loop within a group in sas and do certain conditional operations
My dataset is :

group   val AMT

1   A   12

1   B   06

1   A   31

2   A   77

2   A   32

3   A   43

3   B   76

4   A   32

4   B   44

4   B   23

4   B   11

I want to create a new variable value2 as "A" or "B" with the condition as follows:

if value is B then value2 is B else value2 is A for each group 01,02,03 and so on

for example, the dataset i want is

group   val AMT

1   B   12

1   B   06

1   A   31

2   A   77

2   A   32

3   B   43

3   B   76

4   B   32

4   B   44

4   B   23

4   B   11

Comment: Your logic is unclear. Please post a more detailed example, sample output and whatever you have tried.

Comment: So you want to make a new variable that is exactly the same as the old one?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question for a better understanding. I need the second column (val) to be recreated. If the (val) is "R" BY group then all the values in  (val) should change to "R" else it should remian as "T". Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try the following that makes use of the ifc function that returns a character value based on your condition, i.e. "B" if true, "A" if false:

```
data want;
  set have;
  value2=ifc(value='B','B','A');
run;
```

Comment: Hi Amir, i need to apply conditional logic on the groups level. For eg. here group 01 contains values as A, B, B hence the value of group 01 will be B (x3 times for 3 rows).

Comment: Hi ch1nmay, I suggest you edit your original question to also show all of the output records that should be produced based on the input records you have given, as already suggested by @Reeza.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the max using SQL. The data doesn't make sense in that format, since missing would be blanks, not periods.

```
data have;
infile cards truncover;
input group $ value $;
cards;
01 A
01 B
01 B
02 
02 A
02 A
03 B
03 B
;

proc sql;
create table want as
select *, max(value) as value2
from have 
group by group
order by group, value, value2;
quit;
```